# Laravel пагинатор для many to many

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

У меня есть таблица `parts`, `part_shop`, `shops`

В модели Shops определено many to many отношение

```js
public function parts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Part::class)->withPivot('count');
}
```

Также есть `ShopController`, в нём в `index` мне нужно загрузить данные о магазине, а также товары из этого магазина с пагинацией.

Вот рабочий вариант, но здесь `shop` и `parts` - разные переменные.

```js
public function index(Request $request, string $shop_slug) {
    $shop = Shop::select('id', 'name', 'description', 'warranty', 'delivery_time')
        ->where('slug', $shop_slug)
        ->first();

    $parts = $shop->parts()->paginate(3);

    return Inertia::render('Shop', [
        'shop' => $shop,
        'parts' => $parts
    ]);
}
```

Мне бы хотелось чтобы пагинатор был доступен в `shop->parts`. Я пробовал через `with`. Но вместо пагинатора, там 3 первых элемента элемента, но почему?

```js
public function index(Request $request, string $shop_slug) {
    $shop = Shop::select('id', 'name', 'description', 'warranty', 'delivery_time')
        ->where('slug', $shop_slug)
        ->with(['parts' => function($q) {
            $q->paginate(3);
        }])
        ->first();

    return Inertia::render('Shop', [
        'shop' => $shop,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так воткни их туда.. Запросов в базу кажется меньше не станет.

```
public function index(Request $request, string $shop_slug) {
    $shop = Shop::select('id', 'name', 'description', 'warranty', 'delivery_time')
        ->where('slug', $shop_slug)
        ->first();

    $shop->parts = $shop->parts()->paginate(3);

    return Inertia::render('Shop', [
        'shop' => $shop
    ]);
}
```

Comment: А как можно добавить select для parts?